# Best way to submit/retrieve data from external server, when you have access to external server but not the same domain server

Tags: javascript, php, sdk, xss

I'm working on an SDK type thing for submitting data (including file uploads) to a service that I run.

I'm doing research, and trying to figure out the best way to submit data and get a response to an external server (my server) without being blocked by XSS restrictions.

The current setup is as so:

The customer hosts a server, and uses my server side library.
They generate a client page that loads the required JS from my server.
The client page requests data from my server (if it was not passed from the SDK on page load), and displays the information to the user.
The user then triggers an event, which submits data (potentially including file uploads) to my server (not the local server with the SDK library).
My server responds success or fail and the client JS handles it appropriately.

Some notes:
My server is a private PHP server that I have complete control over.
Although I could route all data through the customer's server (as they are using my library), it is not ideal, as it requires more set up for the customer, is slower for the end user, and handling file uploads is problematic as I want those files on my server, not theirs.
I thought perhaps the file upload inputs could be in an iframe. Will this allow uploads direct to my server?
Since the customer is using my library with an API key, I can authenticate the client's requests by passing an authentication token to the front end on page load that then gets passed to my server with whatever communication method ends up working.

I am open to changes in the architecture, but this is the ideal set up for me. I am just not sure what frontend methods are best for implementing this.

Comment: so, one thing you need to look at is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) - the rest is too broad for SO

Answer (score 0):

[JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) would work if you only need to make GET requests, but it sounds like you need to do POSTs as well since you mention file uploads.

For your case, [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) might work. The short explanation is that a browser will send an extra header named `Origin` if you make a request with `XMLHttpRequest` to another domain. Your server needs to respond with an additional header named `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with a value of `*` or the value the browser sent in the `Origin` header. There are some nuances and gotchas when using CORS, so I recommend reading the link above for a thorough explanation.

With CORS set up, you should be able to use `XMLHttpRequest` to [upload files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16627318)

Comment: I have added a bit more detail to my answer.